# Drush command(s) run on Drupal 6 sites, but not Drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drush

I am running into an issue with a customer's Drupal sites. He has a number of D6 installs, and a new D7 that he's just starting on. **All of these sites are on the same shared hosting package.**

The problem is when running certain `drush` commands *only* on the D7 site. There are no issues on the D6 sites. The specific error for `drush up` on the D7 site follows:

```
foo@bar [~/www/foo]# drush up
Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush   [error]
from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.
Command pm-update needs the following modules installed/enabled to run: update.           [error]
The drush command 'up' could not be executed.                                             [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.                              [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In
this case you can select another site with a working database setup by specifying the URI
to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may
have no access to it in a jailed shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to:
 Drupal version         :  7.28
 Site URI               :  http://default
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database username      :  username_foo
 Database name          :  database_foo
 PHP configuration      :
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush version          :  7.0-dev
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /home/foo/www/foo
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

Everything I can find (and indeed the [link](http://drupal.org/node/1428638) in the error message) say the solution is to change the `host` value in the `settings.php` file from **localhost** to **127.0.0.1**. However, this has not been the solution for us.

- The frontend site has no problems connecting to the database, and `drush` itself seemingly does in many cases too.
- `drush sql-connect` will generate a string that you can use to connect to MySQL.
- `drush sql-cli` will successfully connect to MySQL
- The `settings.php` file is definitely in a folder called `default` (path: `www/foo/sites/default`) and I get the exact same error when specifying `--root` and `--uri` options.
- Drush was originally a ~5.x release, and it had the same issues. We updated to the ~7.x to try to eliminate the error. The host value in `settings.php` has been `localhost` as well as `127.0.0.1` with equally poor results.

We've verified that MySQL is available via socket from the PHP CLI. Drush is up to date and a fresh install. The Drupal 7 site is a brand new fresh install.

I'm at a loss. Why would this work with the D6 sites, but not the D7? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Is your settings.php file in a folder called 'default'? If not, you might need to tell Drush where to find it by using `--uri=mysite.com` or `-l mysite.com`.

There are several ways to specify which Drupal site Drush will target. The most basic option is fairly verbose; run:

```
$ drush --root=/path/to/drupal --uri=http://example.com status
```

You can do the same thing with a slightly different syntax:

```
$ drush /path/to/drupal#example.com status
```

You can also specify the Drupal site implicitly, by setting the cwd to the folder that contains the settings.php file for your site:

cd /path/to/drupal/sites/default # or /path/to/drupal/sites/mysite.com, as appropriate

```
$ drush status
```

In all of the cases above, if settings.php is in a folder called "default", then you do not need to specify the --uri component; you may, for example, cd /path/to/drupal followed by drush status, and the correct Drupal site will be found. If settings.php is not in a folder named 'default', then you will need to either specify --uri, or cd to the folder that contains the settings.php file.

[Source](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/112731/drush-bootstrap-error-on-multi-site-install/112732#112732)

Comment: Thank you for giving some hope, but settings.php is definitely in a folder called default: `www/foo/sites/default` and I get the exact same error when specifying --root and --uri options. If I cd into the `www/foo/sites/default` dir, still get the same errors too. :(

Comment: did you enable  Update module ??

Comment: Enable update module from UI and try running drush up

Comment: try all the possible way you can, that's what I do.  try leaning from failure :)

Comment: Believe me... I've been doing a LOT of failure, er, *learning* on this project. :)

Comment: try installing different version of drush because you are running on dev release can have some issues,  check out this post https://drupal.org/node/881676

Comment: did you check settings.php file, what is your host there?

Comment: Drush was originally a ~5.x release, and it had the same issues. We updated to the ~7.x to try and eliminate the error. The `host` value in settings.php has been **localhost** as well as **127.0.0.1** with equally poor results.

Answer (score 0):

According to this message:

> `pm-update` needs the following modules installed/enabled to run: `update`

Drush requires Update module to be enabled, so the following command should fix the problem:

```
drush -y en update
```